# Watin and Telerik Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, watin

I would like to ask if anybody knows an easy way to test Telerik controls with Watin.

We are about to start using it but before we do I wanted to see if there is anything I would need to know.

The problem that I can see we will be having is that if even smallest thing changes then all our tests will also break.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that you should be testing Telerik's controls - it's their responsibility.

Comment: good point ! but how would you acceptance test the whole system to make sure it is working ?

Answer (score 3):

> The problem that I can see we will be having is that if even smallest thing changes then all our tests will also break.

This could/will be true of all portions of your pages, including Telerik controls, depending on your test structure.  Ideally, your elements will have IDs assigned and you'll use Page classes and custom control objects to remove all HTML references from your actual test code.  Then if something changes on the webpage (or in a control), you verify the change is expected, then you change the WatiN page code (or control code) and re-run your tests.

The WatiN page class primer is here:  http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-page-class.html

Basically, you want to have your test code look like `myPage.PickDate("3/29/2012")` and not like `ie.Tables[3].TableRows[2].TableCells[4].Textbox(Find.ByClass("datePicker")).TypeText("3/29/2012")`

Changes can, do and should result in failing tests, however, I can attest that with a good page (or control) class setup that abstract away the HTML DOM and other specifics leaving non-HTML-filled test code, means that when changes do happen they are most often easy to get working again.

Note: Selenium also has a Page class concept, but I have not used it very much as of right now.  Bottom line:  If you write a lot of tests that reference the HTML DOM directly in test code, you're setting yourself up for a maintenance headache regardless of if you go with WatiN or Selenium or whatever.

Added:  As to your original question: Can you work with Telerik controls in WatiN?  Yes you can most likely, but depending on the control you may need to get a bit creative, possibly even calling javascript methods from within your test (page object ;) ).  I've been stumped by a couple controls (non-Telerik) but most I've eventually figured out.

Comment: As well as the Page class, there is also the Control class, so, although a complex task, you could write a control that encapsulates all the Telerik functionality, and just exposes useful methods (e.g. calendar.PickDate("3/29/2012") or calendar.PageBackOneMonth()). On your page class you would expose the controls e.g. myPage.StartDate.PickDate("3/29/2012") and myPage.EndDate.PickDate("4/29/2012"). As OCary says, this saves you from the world of pain that is maintaining these tests, and makes your tests very readable.

Comment: Even better, with the Page class, you could add helper methods - for instance, on the Login page class, in addition to exposing the Username and Password fields and the Login button, you could add a SignIn(string, string) method that would populate the appropriate fields and simulate the clicking of the button. You can build up a very powerful model of your web application that way.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you asked about WatiN, and I know I'll probably get downvoted into oblivion, but I might recommend `Selenium` instead.  It seems to be more widely used and when we were evaluating the two we found Selenium easier to work with because of the Firefox plugin to record/generate the tests.  This meant that our non-technical folks could set up the tests.

Since then we've successfully used Selenium to test ASP.NET sites that utilize Telerik controls.  I only ran into one issue, with the `RadNumericTextBoxes`, which I've documented a fix for here: http://www.msigman.com/2012/02/entering-radnumerictextbox-selenium-webdriver-1-6-0/.

I'm currently in the process of writing a how-to guide for doing it: http://www.msigman.com/2012/03/automated-testing-asp-net-web-application/ (shameless plug).

Answer (score 1):

You should also consider evaluating [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/), our functional automation test tool. (Disclosure: I'm their evangelist for Test Studio.)

Test Studio really shines when you're working with Telerik controls. You'll get some great additional functionality around being able to dive deeper in to verifications and actions around the controls.

Even more importantly, Test Studio handles centralizing locators and pages by default, so you don't need any additional effort to best manage your UI changes.

Comment: Test Studio also works great for any other controls. We use it for an ASP.NET Winforms application with only standard Microsoft controls.